# Laravel - Unable to variable from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm creating a site in Laravel that uses a controller to validate the information from a form and then return the user to a Thanks page. On that thanks page, I would like to use the user's name and gender.

In my **controller** I have:

```
return redirect()->route('thanks')->with(['success' => 'success', 'name' => $name, 'gender' => $gender]);
```

Then, in the **view**, I have:

```
<p>{{ $name }}</p>
<p>{{ $gender }}</p>
```

But, for some reason I keep getting this error:

Undefined Variable: Name

What's weird is that if I die and dump $name within the controller, it shows it properly on the screen.

I've tried various different ways to try to pass multiple variables through to the view as well as different variable names and forms to receive it again... but haven't been able to make it work.

Do you guys have any idea where I could be going wrong? As, always, I really appreciate your help! All ideas, suggestions, and comments are welcome :) Thanks!!

Comment: That's not code to display a view, that's a redirect..

Comment: I would +1 just for *What's weird is that **if I die and dump** $name within the controller, it shows it properly on the screen.*

Comment: @Devon, any idea how to get the code to be pushed back into the view? I have also tried return redirect()->route('thanks')->withInput(['success' => 'success', 'name' => $name, 'gender' => $gender]); with no luck, unfortunately.

Comment: That's still a redirect, where's the code that returns your view..

Comment: @AI.G. Haha! :) I mean:

echo "<pre>\n";var_dump($name);die;

Comment: @Devon - the route('thanks') part returns the view itself. That is working as it returns the user to the thanks page.

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data), it seems sth like `return redirect('thanks')->with('var', 'value');` should work.

Comment: No, that redirects to the route thanks.  Nothing in your controller does anything with a view.  Redirect with() sets session data.  I'd recommend you read through the docs.

Comment: @Al.G.  session data is not the same as view variables.

Comment: at AI.G. , yeah, that worked with return redirect()->route('thanks')->with('success', 'success')... So, I was able to return to the thanks page and was able to print out success in the console like this:

@if(session()->has('success'))
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    console.log('success');
                });
            </script>
        @endif

Comment: @Devon you're right… I was about to clean my comment but it seems it worked for OP.

Comment: @Devon, yeah, I've definitely been reading through the docs... unfortunately, couldn't find exactly what I was looking for in terms of passing two variables back to the view :(

Comment: @AI.G., it worked.... sort of... but as Devon was saying, that only worked for the session data. It didn't allow me to pass any variables

Comment: Yeah, it's because you're not understanding that view variables are set wherever the 'thanks' route is, not from a redirect.

Comment: @Devon... you're absolutely right. I'm not understanding something :( So, would you suggest putting this within its own function in the controller?

Comment: For example, my thanks route is simply set in the Web.php file:

Route::get('/thanks', function () {
    App::setlocale('en');
    return view('thanks');
})->name('thanks');

Comment: Well, you can either return the view and pass the variables from here instead of redirecting, or pull the data from the session if you want to use session flashing.

Comment: Nice!!!! That was it! I found it! So, here is what I did instead: return redirect('thanks')->with(['success' => 'success', 'name' => $name, 'gender' => $gender]);  Thanks so much @Devon and AI.G: :) :) Let me know if either of you guys wants to write that as the answer. I can then accept that as the answer :) otherwise, I'll write it in ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with() on a redirect flashes data to the session, it does not involve anything with views.  You shouldn't confuse this method call with views and redirects as they are not equivalent.

The only place where variables are passed to the view is where you're returning the view:

```
return view('thanks')->with(['success' => 'success', 'name' => $name, 'gender' => $gender]);
```

Since you're using a redirect, you would need to pull this data from the session to pass into the view (or access the data from the session directly in the view).

Or you could just return this view from your controller instead of redirecting in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you redirect to URL with data then you can get the data form session.

```
return redirect()->route('thanks')->with(['success' => 'success', 'name' => $name, 'gender' => $gender]);
```

write in your view

```
{{ Session::get('name') }}

{{ Session::get('gender) }}
```

And if you redirect direct to the view like this

```
return view('thanks')->with(['success' => 'success', 'name' => $name, 'gender' => $gender]);
```

then write in your view

```
<p>{{ $name }}</p>
<p>{{ $gender }}</p>
```